# Converting Regex to Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following regex.

```
/http:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+/g
```

Which identifies matching URL's (https://regex101.com/r/sG9zR7/1). I need to modify it in order to  be able to use it on the command line so it prints out the results.   so I modified it to following

```
sed -n 's/.*\(http:\/\/\([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.\)+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\).*/\1/p' filename
```

(I was trying to add bold to the characters added but could not)
there were as follows

**sed -n 's/.*(**  (in the beginning )

**\**    (For the inner parenthesis)

**).*/\1/p' filename**    (at the end)

However, i get no results when i execute it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460 and post some testable sample input and expected output. Also, you do not need to escape `-` at the start or end of a bracket expression and you should be using POSIX character classes instead of hard-coded character ranges (which are locale-dependent) so your regexp should be `/http:\/\/([[:alnum:]-]+\.)+[[:alnum:]-]+:[[:alnum:]-]+\/[[:alpha:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]+/g` and note that `+` requires EREs so sed will need the `-r` flag or escape every `+`: `\+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make it a habit to use a delimiter other that `/` when dealing with
>   URLs. It makes the pattern easier to read.

```
sed -r -n 's~.*\(http://\([a-z0-9\-]+\.\)+[a-z0-9\-]+:[a-z0-9\-]+/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\).*~\1~ip' file
```

Note that I use `i` modifier for ignorecase.

As [hwnd comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671565/converting-regex-to-sed/32671701?noredirect=1#comment53189067_32671701), you should put `-r` flag to sed command as well since your pattern requires `+` to be treated in a special manner.

Comment: I like the "i" I was unaware of that. Regex seems to work with the exception of the  misses,which i understand. as is; i  get 192 matches.   I have to see what the ?: does.   that was all that was added to the expression.  the new expression return 0 hits.

Comment: @user68650 ignore the `?:` in pattern. It got carried forward from my test cases. I have also removed it above

Comment: i had to  start over with the guidance provided -  the above sample did not work when i applied the -r  has something to do when ans where the escpare sewquence was being applied.  so i had to test each one.   this is the working command --- sed -rn 's~.*(http://([a-z0-9\-]+.)*[a-z0-9\-]+:[0-9]+\/[a-z0-9]+.[a-z]+).*~\1~ip' Filename

Answer (score 0):

`sed -rn 's~.*(http://([a-z0-9\-]+.)*[a-z0-9\-]+:[0-9]+\/[a-z0-9]+.[a-z]+).*~\1~ip' Filename` is the working command. With the assistance of the sample supplied (thank you hjpotler92) I was able to figure out the escape character did not need to be applies to certain characters.   Will have to find out when and how it is applied when using the -r option.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with an xpath query via [xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html):

```
xidel file.html -e '//a/@href[fn:matches(.,"http://[^/]*:")]/fn:substring-after(.,"=")'
```